# How do I change Jag Guardian questions?

Tags: runescape

How do I change my JAG account guardian questions? I think someone has discovered them and has added an unauthorized computer. I deleted it but I don't want him/her to add it again and access my account.

Comment: Don't see why this was heavily downvoted. Sure, the description is rather low quality, but there really isn't anything more he can say. It's a legitimate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

According to the [official FAQ of Jagex Account Guardian](http://services.runescape.com/m=rswiki/en/Jagex%20Account%20Guardian), you can only set the questions once and you can not change them for security reasons.

The FAQ also mentions:

> If you are unable to recall your security answers, you will not be able to make any further changes to JAG; this includes adding and removing devices.